# Failed QWT plugin

Tags: qt, plugins, qt-creator

I have been trying for many, many hours across multiple operating systems to get QT up and running with QWT plotting library. It has been an absolute nightmare, and I'm very close to forgetting the entire thing. I would be extremely grateful for some help from a more experienced user.

Working in Ubuntu linux, I've installed QT and QWT according to the instructions here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OjBpu8f0BJE (no errors along the way)

However, when in design view within QT Creator, I don't get any QWT widgets to show up. A check to Plugin Information shows that it is listed as a failed plugin with the following message:
"Cannot load library %FILEPATH%libqwt_designer_plugin.so: (libqwt.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
BUT, when I follow the filepath in terminal, the file libqwt_designer_plugin.so does actually exist! What do I need to do in order to get QWT working here? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the video and it seems that the default install directory is really odd (`/usr/local/qwt-5.2.4-svn/`). Possibly you can run Qt Creator with

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/qwt-5.2.4-svn/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH qtcreator
```

where `/usr/local/qwt-5.2.4-svn/lib` path contains the installed library `libqwt.so.5` (but check if it's really there).

You'll have to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable even to run your QWT apps outside Qt Creator.

Other solution is to install the library in other path. Supposedly `make INSTALL_ROOT=/usr/local install` should work but I didn't test it and later you could have problems removing the installed library.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will check into that and see if that resolves.

I fancy myself fairly technically competent, but this whole process has made me feel like a moron.